# EF 4 with LINQ to Entities crashes when using Contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I use a WCF Data Service and have a LINQ to Entities query that works fine:

```
var result = 
   (from data1 in context.Data
    join info in context.Information on data1.inf_ID equals info.ID
    select info );
return result.AsQueryable();
```

If I use the following code:

```
string[] ids ={"1","2","3"};

var result = 
   (from data1 in context.Data
    join info in context.Information on data1.inf_ID equals info.ID
    where ids.Contains(info.ID.ToString())
    select info);
return result.AsQueryable();
```

I get the following exception and stacktrace:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Stacktrace: at: System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at: System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at: System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.InvokeServiceOperation(ServiceOperation serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataServiceProvider.InvokeServiceOperation(ServiceOperation serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceProviderWrapper.InvokeServiceOperation(OperationWrapper serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForServiceOperation(SegmentInfo segment, IDataService service, Boolean checkRights, SegmentInfo lastSegment)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForSegments(ICollection`1 parsedSegments, IDataService service)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequestUri()
at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()

INNER EXCEPTION: null
Stacktrace: at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
at: System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at: System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at: System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
at: System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
at: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
at: System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at: System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at: InfoService.GetIDS(String ids) at: InfoService.svc.cs, line: 507

at: System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at: System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at: System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.InvokeServiceOperation(ServiceOperation serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.EntityFrameworkDataServiceProvider.InvokeServiceOperation(ServiceOperation serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.Providers.DataServiceProviderWrapper.InvokeServiceOperation(OperationWrapper serviceOperation, Object[] parameters)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForServiceOperation(SegmentInfo segment, IDataService service, Boolean checkRights, SegmentInfo lastSegment)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ComposeExpressionForSegments(ICollection`1 parsedSegments, IDataService service)
at: System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequestUri()
at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
```

I've learned that EF4 supports Contains. How can I create a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use a string array and the info.ID.ToString() method, stay with your int/double/decimal.. and it will work out.

You have to use the following method to convert the int to string and make a where clause:
**SqlFunctions.StringConvert** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466276.aspx

**Edit:**

```
//if info.ID is a string this is sufficient (.ToString() was removed)
string[] ids ={"1","2","3"};

var result = 
   (from data1 in context.Data
    join info in context.Information on data1.inf_ID equals info.ID
    where ids.Contains(info.ID)
    select info);
return result.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I don't have ints in my code. I have to use string in the array and the IDs are also strings. How can I use them?

Comment: just remove the .ToString() Method than, why do you call it when ID is already a string? See edit in my answer

Comment: A ToString() killed the Contains? Strange. I modified similarly to this and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to see my answer helped you out. EntityFramework doesnt know how to translate the .ToString() Method to sql and therefor you should be using the SqlFunctions.xxx (like StringConvert), but if the ID is already a string it didnt really make sense to call it anyway.